# How i set data dynamically on variable in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need some help. How I set data dynamically on a variable in flutter?. I have a form inside listview.builder. which number of TextFormField generated dynamically. So it's hard to make a different variable for each TextFormField.
When username text in TextFormField I want setState that data on a `var` so that I can store that data in firebase. Here how my simple version of my code:

```
Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: widget.stops,

                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              var stops = 1;

                              return Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Flexible(
                                    child: Container(
                                      child: TextFormField(
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          labelText: 'Stop ' +
                                              (stops + index).toString(), 
                                        ),
                                        validator: (val) => val.isEmpty
                                            ? 'Cannot be empty'
                                            : null,
                                        onChanged: (val) {
                                          setState(() {
                                             //here i want setdata dynamically
                                         });
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Flexible(
                                    child: Container(     
                                      child: TextFormField(
                                        cursorColor: Color(0xFF127772),
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          labelText: 'Ticket Price',
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        validator: (val) => val.isEmpty
                                            ? 'Cannot be empty'
                                            : null,
                                        onChanged: (val) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            //here i want setdata dynamically
                                          });
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              );
                            }),
                      ),
                      Container(                   
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          ),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {}
                          },                    
                          child: Text('CREATE'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two list of String as you have two textField in in item and assign val to this list on onsave method.

Following code help you more to understand.

```
class DeleteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final stops = 2;
  @override
  _DeleteWidgetState createState() => _DeleteWidgetState();
}

class _DeleteWidgetState extends State<DeleteWidget> {
  List<String> _list1;
  List<String> _list2;
  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _list2 = List(widget.stops);
    _list1 = List(widget.stops);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: widget.stops,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                  return Row(
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                        child: TextFormField(
                          validator: (val) =>
                              val.isEmpty ? 'Cannot be empty' : null,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(
                              () {
                                _list1[index] = val;
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 20,
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: TextFormField(
                          validator: (val) =>
                              val.isEmpty ? 'Cannot be empty' : null,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(
                              () {
                                _list2[index] = val;
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    _formKey.currentState.save();
                    for (int i = 0; i < widget.stops; i++) {
                      print("item $i form field 1 ${_list1[i]}");
                      print("item $i form field 2 ${_list2[i]}");
                    }
                  }
                },
                child: Text('CREATE'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```